# Log4Net SMTP send data as table

Tags: smtp, log4net

Hello everyone I try to get first an XML after that I will use "XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j.cs" layout.My problem is it doesnt work.

Here is the code :

```
 protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("LogDate");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Date",loggingEvent.TimeStamp.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Thread",loggingEvent.ThreadName);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Log Level",loggingEvent.Level.DisplayName);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Logger",loggingEvent.LoggerName);
        writer.WriteStartElement("Message");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("BankCode", loggingEvent.Properties["BankCode"].ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("PackageId", loggingEvent.Properties["PackageId"].ToString());
        writer.WriteStartElement("Message");
        writer.WriteString(loggingEvent.Properties["Message"].ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Exception");
        writer.WriteString(loggingEvent.Properties["Exception"].ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();

    }
```

My config :

```
 <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="C:\blabla\qqqq.txt" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: _"I have problem"_ doesn't help very much. Why don't you just use [XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4net/tags/log4net-1_2_9/src/Layout/XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j.cs)?

Comment: How.. Am I right in the code ? . My problem is it doesnt work i found it in tutorial

Comment: _"My problem is it doesnt work"_ doesn't help much either.

Comment: Thank you I edited.

Comment: You would either specify `<layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">` to use the built in log4j formatter, or if you want to use your own you would register the type, e.g. `<layout type="CustomLog4NetNamespace.CustomPatternLayout, CustomLog4NetNamespace">`

Comment: ı will try now ı write the result

Comment: Result is great I ovveride and create my own layout but one thing is missing can you look answer please :) I will say thank your for help..

Answer (score 0):

> **Only one thing is missing now in my xml this part when I close my service it's log perfect but when I start it doesnt write into xml.**

```
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 086[1] INFO Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory Using
default implementation
for object serializer
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 335[1] INFO Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory Using
default implementation
for ThreadExecutor
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 367[1] INFO Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 367[1] INFO Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler Quartz Scheduler v.0.0.0.0 created.
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 382[1] INFO Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin Registering Quartz Job Initialization Plug - in .
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 382[1] INFO Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore RAMJobStore initialized.
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 398[1] INFO Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler Scheduler meta - data: Quartz Scheduler(v0.0.0.0)
'QuartzScheduler'
with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
Scheduler class: 'Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
Using job - store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence.and is not clustered.

2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 398[1] INFO Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory Quartz scheduler 'QuartzScheduler'
initialized
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 398[1] INFO Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory Quartz scheduler version: 0.0.0.0
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 476[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Parsing XML file: C: \TmsfQuartz\ quartz_jobs.xml with systemId: ~/quartz_jobs.xml
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 725[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding 9 jobs, 9 triggers.
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 725[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: SendPackageGroup.SendPackageJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 725[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: ExportPackageGroup.ExportPackageJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 741[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: CreatePackageGroup.CreatePackageJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 741[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: ProcessPackageGroup.ProcessPackageJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 741[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: ExcelStorageProcessGroup.ExcelStorageProcessJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 741[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: SendBulkPackageFirstGroup.SendBulkPackageFirstGroupJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 741[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: SendBulkPackageSecondGroup.SendBulkPackageSecondGroupJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 741[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: SendBulkPackageThirdGroup.SendBulkPackageThirdGroupJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 741[16] INFO Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor Adding job: SendBulkPackageFourthGroup.SendBulkPackageFourthGroupJob
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 757[16] INFO Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2017 - 01 - 16 17: 03: 53, 757[16] INFO Quartz.Server.QuartzServer Scheduler started successfully
```

My Config now :

```
 <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <param name="File" value="C:\log.txt" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="EDistraintDataAccess.Helper.EhacizLog4NetLayout" />
</appender>
```